# Testing new site (not secure yet); using Search/Contact switches to secure url

Tags: wordpress, ssl, civicrm-contact

Working on a new install (haven't installed CA certified SSL yet), I can browse to http://example...admin...event search ( search participants) or 'advanced search', or 'manage events', or seemingly any other menu items but going to 'search contacts' the url generated has ' search'
It is a WP frontend and the baseUrl doesn't specify httpS:// yet.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to try, in this order:

- **Administer menu » System Settings » Resource URLs**.  Ensure "Force Secure URLs" is set to "No".
- Clear cache and templates_c.
- Rebuild the menu: 
   `http://<wordpress_site>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1`

Comment: Also check the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in the civicrm.settings.php file.